# Lost my company ID card on first week of work. How to report this to my supervisor?

Tags: professionalism, security

*Update*

Luckily, a colleague found my card and handed it back to our secretary. Seems that I forgot it in a meeting room. Thanks everybody for the suggestions anyway.

---

I started to work in a new company just on Monday. This is a large company and my work place is located in a building complex where all employees are required to carry/wear a company ID to enter the building (this is just a pocket size card with a picture and a magnetic band). I received my ID card on the first day of work and I used it yesterday and the day before to enter the office.
But today, I could not find my ID any more. I told the security that I forgot it at home so I was let in anyway, but I'm afraid I lost it yesterday on my way back home, maybe because I didn'the fix it well to my clothes. To be honest I'm not completely sure that I lost it. Might as well find it again later at home but I don't have a good feeling about this.
What is the best thing to do in my situation? Should I wait or report the loss to my supervisor immediately? I'm new to this company and I don't want to appear like an unreliable person.

Answer (score 14):

Report the loss immediately. In a big company, there are standard procedures for such things, some of which assume that the employee who lost the ID badge reports so immediately - for security reasons.

Yeah it looks bad, but it looks worse to wait it out.

Comment: If you think you may have left it at home, I would at least check there first.Then report it the next day.  Reporting immediately when it may not even be lost seems a bit premature.

Comment: @dan1111, I tend to disagree.  If they did in fact lose it, and it's used to enter the building by someone else, telling your higher ups would allow for them to know it's not really you, and someone is there that shouldn't be.  If OP happens to find it, then OP can tell the bosses and all can be done.  But saying "hey, I have misplaced my ID badge, not sure if it's lost or if I just left it at home, but just wanted to say something in case it is in fact lost" is not unreasonable.

Answer (score 7):

Seems to me, like you don't have much choice. You want to tell immediately, because you simply need it for authorization at gates. I would recommend an approach to offer a payment if needed for new card, although if it's bigger company you probably won't need to pay it at all. It happened and happens to people all the time and you don't need to be worried for getting unreliable person reputation for thing small like this.

Comment: "Offer a payment"? Never. And a company should never accept a payment, because that would mean it's Ok to lose your card as long as you pay.

Comment: offer a payment should never be done. However it is possible that said company has a ID-card loss policy. My company has the policy if you lose your company ID-card within a year of receiving it you are charged €15,-

Comment: @gnasher729 Last company I worked for has a 10 dollars processing fee for the cards since it contained a token.

Comment: @Dan: The point is that accepting a payment means that losing your card is Ok, as long as you pay. In your last company you might have said "lost my card, no big deal, 10 dollars, that's three coffees" instead of saying "oh ****, I wonder what some criminal could do if he finds my card".

Comment: @gnasher729 and that's why you directly report it. There should be security policy's in place that takes the card out of the system and thus void.

Comment: i didn' meant directly to offer some cash, but in sign of respect you can let them know that you will pay for new one if needed.